# Is there any way through which I can integrate firebase realtime database with node.js server?

Tags: node.js, firebase

Is there any tutorial, articles or blog available on this topic? Please share.

Answer (score 1):

**Video Getting Started**

> [Getting Started with the Firebase Realtime Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=noB98K6A0TY)

**Quickstart for Node.js**

> [Firebase Node.js Realtime Database Quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-nodejs/tree/master/database)

**Blog**

> [Firebase Tutorial Building a Realtime App with Firebase](https://www.airpair.com/firebase/posts/firebase-building-realtime-app)
>
> [Getting started with Firebase real-time database for the web](https://medium.com/evenbit/getting-started-with-firebase-real-time-database-for-the-web-f53b527aae27)
>
> [A Basic Guide to Firebase For The Web](http://http:/http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/a-basic-guide-to-firebase-for-the-web/10142)

**Documentation**

> [Firebase Database Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start)